# Отличие вызовов js и jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, canvas

Всем доброго времени суток, назрел один небольшой вопрос, почему это работает:

```
$('#bigTable3').append('<canvas id="schedule">schedule</canvas>');
var schedule = document.getElementById("schedule").getContext("2d");
```

а это:

```
$('#bigTable3').append('<canvas id="schedule">schedule</canvas>');
var schedule = $('#schedule').getContext("2d");
```

и даже это:

```
$('#bigTable3').append('<canvas id="schedule">schedule</canvas>');
var schedule = $('#schedule');
var graph = schedule.getContext("2d");
```

нет!

Вообще честно говоря стало интересно, что вообще вызывает jQuery, и чем оно так разительно отличается от того что получает чистый js при вызове id,clss,name.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: jQuery возвращает jQuery объект с различного вида информацией внутри при любых селекторах, а селектор на чистом js  - элемент

Comment: дак в отладчике добавьте две переменных да сравните

Comment: зы: вам видимо `$('#schedule')[0].getContext("2d");` надо, либо `.get(0)`

Comment: а в чём разница, я думал если id, то он единственный и неповторимый, зачем [0] о_О ?

Comment: @Owl потому что jquery объект....... особенность хранения данных такая у него....... сделайте в консоли на этой странице `$('#custom-header')` и гляньте ..... а потом `$('.prettyprint')`

Comment: то есть это не есть DOM-элемент. это jquery объект, у которого есть коллекция DOM-элементов, подходящих под селектор. Чтобы получить сам DOM-элемент нужно взять его из этой коллекции.

Answer (score 3):

На чистом *Javascript* селектор выбирает DOM-элемент (или коллекцию, в зависимости от селектора). Если на текущей странице в консоли написать `document.getElementById("custom-header")`, то выведется

```
<div id=​"custom-header">​</div>​
```

C этим элементом можно производить разные действия, которые "прикреплены" к HTMLElement'у

---

*Jquery* же при выборке возвращает объект, в котором хранится множество данных о выборке. Вот что вернет *Jquery* при запросе `$('#custom-header')` на текущей странице:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не хилый такой объект с информацией.

Далее... При вызове `$('.prettyprint')`  на текущей странице будет заметно, что выбрано три элемента (0,1,2):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему при выборке одного элемента на *Jquery* приходится писать `$('#Selector')[0]` или  надо, либо `$('#Selector').get(0)` ? Ну видимо они решили пусть будет список всегда, только при одном элементе - будет один объект в списке, а при нескольких - много. Иначе бы пришлось для выборки одного элемента перекраивать возвращаемый объект. А зачем?